# Is /data/data/ a reliable assumption for installation path?

Tags: android, node.js, android-ndk

I am messing around with node.js on Android through [this project](https://github.com/paddybyers/anode), and I need a way to deploy js files to a private directory (to hide the source code, and prevent users from tampering) which also **physically exists on the filesystem** (an apparent requirement for node.js).

Is it correct to place my javascript files in `/data/data/com.skabbes.android/node_modules`? And if not, what would be the correct way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are wanting to store something on the internal storage, it is not recommended to use an absolute path like `/data/data/..../` because while that may be the correct path, it can potentially change with different devices or different Android versions because /data/data/ the internal file structure is not specified in official Android documentation.

I also want to point out that even if you are storing information in the /data/ directory it is still possible that someone could access it if they have a rooted phone.

But, what you should do is see [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). That will save information on the internal storage of the device and neither the user nor other apps can access the files you save with that method unless the device is rooted.

Comment: I guess rooted phones are an accepted risk, no way to really get around that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `getFilesDir()` method of `Context` which basically abstracts the absolute path.

It will most probably be something like `/data/data/<package-name>/files` but it's a better way to make sure your app is compatible with all versions of Android and all devices.